# Idle Queue utilization in Capacity Scheduler - EMR

Tags: amazon-emr

I configured capacity scheduler and schedule jobs in specific Queues. However, I see there are times when jobs in some Queues complete faster while other Queues have jobs waiting on the previous ones to commplete. This creates a scenario where half of my capacity is idle and other half is busy with jobs waiting to get resources.

Is there any config that I can tweak to maximize my utilization. I want to route waiting jobs to other queues where resources are available. Attached is a screenshot - 
[image]

Comment: Is it even possible with capacity-scheduler

Comment: Seems like an issue with Capacity-Scheduler here, I switched to Fair-scheduler and definitely see huge improvements in cluster utilization, ~75% and way better than 40s with caoacity-scheduler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like an issue with Capacity-Scheduler here, I switched to Fair-scheduler and definitely see huge improvements in cluster utilization, ~75% and way better than 40s with caoacity-scheduler

Answer (score 0):

So the reason behind is when multiple users submits jobs to a same queue it can consume max resources, but a single user can't consume more than the capacity even though max capacity is greater than that.
So if you specify `yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.QUEUE-1.capacity: 20` this to *capacity-scheduler.xml* **one** user can't take more than 20% resources for QUEUE-1 queue even though your cluster have free resources.

By default this **user-limit-factor** is set to `1`. So if you set it to `2` your job can use 40% of resources if maximum allocated resources is greater than or equals to 40.

```
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.QUEUE-1.user-limit-factor: 2
```

Please follow this [blog](https://blog.cloudera.com/yarn-capacity-scheduler/)